# How do I get rid of blank error page with "You are not allowed to access this action." in decl_auth in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, declarative-authorization

The authorization works nicely, but when a user accesses an action/controller that they don't have access to, they see:

```
You are not allowed to access this action
```

The page is blank.

How do I customize what the user sees ? Either by replacing the message altogether, to replacing the page with a new page altogether ?

How would I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a plugin or a filter to make authorization in you app ?

Comment: I am using declarative_authorization - which is an authorization gem.

Answer (score 3):

To handle this, I added a **permission_denied** method in the **ApplicationController**:

```
def permission_denied
  flash[:notice] = "Sorry, you are not authorized to access that page." 
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

See last section of this Railscast: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization